# Библиотека для работы с 2D графикой на С

Tags: c

Нужна библиотека для работы с 2D графикой с более-менее вменяемой документацией, описанием, для создания 2D игры. Язык программирования С.

Comment: Под С в голову приходит только Cairo, но работать с GTK+ в винде то еще удовольствие + нет нормального описания этой библиотеки. Если ошибаюсь, укажите, где можно нормально почитать про нее.

Comment: Можно asm-вставками через int 10h :D

Answer (score 4):

[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) в помощь.

Comment: Это конечно не плохо, но тогда выплывает другой вопрос: как библиотеку SDL.dll прикрутить к С-ой программе? Я понимаю что нужен заглавный файл с прототипами всех функций библиотеки, но такого фала не было обнаружено в скачанном архиве!

Comment: Качаете архив с runtime libraries (там dll) и один из архивов development libraries (там инклудники) (vc6, vc8 или mingw32, смотря чем будете компилировать).

Comment: Да, и впрямь это уже другой вопрос. Ну уж это точно можно нагуглить, к тому же на сайте libsdl есть и нужные файлы, и нужная информация.

Comment: Я задал вопрос чтобы сразу получить ответ от людей которые этим пользовались, а не тратить время на гуглежку!

Comment: Так давайте задачу, я ее напишу, чтобы вы не тратили время на кодирование.

Comment: Отлично, к нам еще и претензии.

Если не понятно, повторю еще раз, переходишь по [ссылке](http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php), там скачиваешь рантайм под нужную систему (сама библиотека) + девелопмент под нужную систему и под нужный компилятор/среду разработки (там файлы .h и .lib).

Comment: Нет к вам никаких претензий, конечно спасибо за помощь(insolor).
А ваша ирония (1101_debian - юморист) здесь была лишней.

Comment: Здесь была лишней ваша наглость. Я не поленился нагуглить офф сайт SDL, ответил на вопрос -> потратил свое время, а в ответ вижу "мне впадлу гуглить".

Comment: Вот здесь вы не правы, мне не "впадло гуглить", мне было интересно увидеть мнение людей работавших с этой библиотекой, грубо говоря, совет, что, где и как лучше использовать, исходя из их личного опыта.  Они имели смысл не "мне впадло гуглить", а "мне интересно увидеть совет работавших с библиотекой". "Гуглить" я умею, не беспокойтесь, но я думал что здесь люди пишут ответы из своего собственного опыта, а не "нагуглив", так что никого я не заставлял "гуглить" вместо меня, не преувеличивайте. 
Так что нечего меня окидывать дерьмом из-за неправильной интерпретации вами моих слов!

Comment: И приношу извинения пользователю insolor, так как 4 комментарий(из-за которого начался этот холивар)был адресован 1101_debian.